# Sum Rows Where Indexes Between Certain Numbers - Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv with the following format

```
       Time     Marker
0       2104    21
1       2109    20
2       2485    21
3       2491    20
4       2867    22
5       2997    2
6       3248    23
```

and I want to count the incidences of 21, 22, and 23s in between the Marker==20. The only valid markers are bookended between 20 codes so, that first 21 isn't valid. Multiple valid markers can occur within the bookended pair of 20s so I need a count of 21,22 and 23s that occur BETWEEN a pair of 20s.

So, in the example above, only index 2 could be a valid code since it's between two 20s.

I have a list of the indexes where the Marker==20 condition is met

```
Indexrange = df.index[df['Marker'] == 20].tolist()
[1,
 3,
 10,
 19,
 22,
 25,
 29,
 32,]
```

How do I loop through the list of indexes and count the incidence of each 21,22,23 per pair of 20s?

So far I have:

```
TwentyOnes=0
TwentyTwos=0
TwentyThrees=0

for i in Indexrange:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if index.between(i, i+1):
            if Marker == 21
                Count_of_21s +=
            if Marker == 22
                Count_of_22s +=
            if Marker == 23
                Count_of_23s +=
            else:
                InvalidCount+=
```

but I'm getting

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-4a72c2a77924> in <module>()
  5 for i in Indexrange:
  6     for index, row in df.iterrows():
----> 7         if index.between(i,i+1):
  8             print(index, row['Marker'])

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'between'
```

How do I only get to the values between pairs of 20s/between the indexes in the IndexRange?

Output desired would be: Counts_of_21s = int, Counts_of_22s = int, Counts_of_23s = int, InvalidCount = int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you need

```
df.groupby(df.Marker.eq(20).cumsum()).Marker.value_counts()
Out[1013]: 
Marker  Marker
0       21        1
1       20        1
        21        1
2       2         1
        20        1
        22        1
        23        1
Name: Marker, dtype: int64
```

Update

```
df=df.assign(yourid=df.Marker.eq(20).cumsum())
df.loc[(df.yourid<df.yourid.max())&(df.yourid>df.yourid.min())&(df.Marker!=20),:].groupby('yourid').Marker.value_counts()
Out[1021]: 
yourid  Marker
1       21        1
Name: Marker, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Close, but it doesn't solve the initial invalid 21 issue. In the given example, the only valid code would be index 2, because it's between a pair of 20s.

Comment: That really is a great solution.  A lot better than mine below since it will pick up ever value, not just the hardcoded ones I have.

Answer (score 1):

This was my solution:

```
import pandas as pd

csv_df = pd.read_csv('between.txt')

markers = csv_df['Marker'].tolist()
indexrange = csv_df.index[csv_df['Marker'] == 20].tolist()
list_dicts = []

for x in range(len(indexrange)-1):
    currentgroup = {'21': markers[indexrange[x]:indexrange[x+1]].count(21),
                    '22': markers[indexrange[x]:indexrange[x+1]].count(22),
                    '23': markers[indexrange[x]:indexrange[x+1]].count(23)
                    }
    list_dicts.append(currentgroup)

i = 1
for list in list_dicts:
    print(f'Grouping {i}', list)
    i = i+1
```

Wen's is a great deal better.